# Hadoop Configured getConf() returning null

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, hadoop

I have a Spring MVC application running on tomcat which submits MapReduce jobs and analyzes results. My Spring Batch tasklet is able to successfully call an MR driver class and run the job. The driver class extends `Configured` and implements `Tool` and is easily able to manipulate HDFS files. The maven module containing the driver class and MR code is added as a dependency to the webapp module.

For analysis, I created a new class in the webapp module which extends `Configured`. This class is supposed to read an HDFS file and analyze it. However when I try to create the `FileSystem` object I am getting a null pointer exception.

```
public class ReportAnalyzer extends Configured{

    public void analyze(String path) throws Exception{
        FileSystem hdfs=FileSystem.get(getConf()); <-- NPE

        //create Path, etc.
    }
}
```

Is there anything else that needs to be done in order to get the `FileSystem` object? the hadoop dependencies are added to the webapp via the mapreduce module.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to implement `Configured(Configuration conf)` constructor

```
public ReportAnalyzer(Configuration conf){
    super(conf);
}
```

or use `setConf()` before calling `analyze()`.

Comment: Both of these approaches require me to have the Configuration object, which I was trying to get automatically populated from the classpath as happens when we use it in a driver class.

Comment: Using `Configuration` constructor `new Configuration()` will suffice if only you have proper hadoop configuration xmls in your classpath.